# selecting phone from iphone contacts

Tags: iphone

I am a new comer in iphone development.I am developing an application for iphone which needs to select phone number and name from iphone contacts .I used "ABPeoplePickerNavigationController" class to open the contacts view.I need to show some instructions which guides the user to select the phone number when the contacts view opens.Is there any way to do this ?Because the contacts view covers the entire parent view ..Looking for a solution

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add a subview to the contacts view, it should overlay that view and you can put instructions there.